# Simple String program but getting wrong output with no Runtime error

Tags: java, string

I am solving a problem in HackerRank.

**Task:**

Given a string,S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line (see the Sample below for more detail).

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer, T (the number of test cases). 
Each line i of the T subsequent lines contain a String, S .

**Output Format**

For each String Sj (where ), print Sj's even-indexed characters, followed by a space, followed by Sj's odd-indexed characters.

**Sample Input**

2

Hacker

Rank

**Sample Output**

Hce akr

Rn ak

**Following is the Code I have written:**

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        for(int j = 0; j< str.length() ; j++){
            if(j%2 ==0){
                System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
            }                
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j< str.length() ; j++){
            if(j%2==1 ){
                System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Now My Output is differing with the Test Case Output:

**Testcase 0**
Your code did not pass this test case.

**Input (stdin)**

2

Hacker

Rank

**Your Output (stdout)**

_______________   // first line is getting skipped but if i comment the System.out.println at the end of loop then both string are coming on same line

Hce akr

Rn ak

**Expected Output**

Hce akr

Rn ak

**Compiler Message**

Wrong Answer

I want to know whats wrong with my Program as per my knowledge I am not making any mistakes. Why after first time String Manipulation it is exiting loop?

Here is the link for Whole question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem

**One Question Added**
you can see if we are putting System.out.println() at the end of loop I am getting extra line in my output but when i m skipping it my program is working fine but as there is no linebreak between my output both are sticking together and coming like this: hce akrRn ak. U see this is my main problem. I want to get the output in sperate lines.

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger?

Comment: There appears to be a bunch of words missing from your task specification. Please try and write stuff that makes sense.

Comment: Can you try changing the "<=" condition in for loop to "<" and try

Comment: I have edited it. Please check now

Comment: Already tried that but no change in output. Instead it takes N-1 test cases

Answer (score 2):

Well there are few mistakes which I found in your code which could be the reason for failure :

> for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)

There should be condition like i < n.

Also you are printing the output one by one i.e. as soon as user gave first input out of n you are printing it.

```
2
Hacker
Hce akr
Rank
Rn ak
```

Here I modified the code which you are using hope you ry to understand it first before using :

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i< n; i++){
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            String s1 ="";
            for(int j = 0; j< str.length() ; j++){
                if(j%2 ==0){
                    s1 = s1 + str.charAt(j);
                }                
            }
            s1 = s1 + " ";
            for(int j = 0; j< str.length() ; j++){
                if(j%2==1 ){
                    s1 = s1 + str.charAt(j);
                }
            }
            list.add(s1);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code work's properly there's no question on it. But One question though, Do we have to use List to program. also want to know why my program is getting out of loop in first attempt. I mean loops should go on until it reach N.

Comment: @user26837 : You never came out of loop as I explained above also after each input your output is in next line not waiting to complete the whole input cycle and that's where list comes into picture which will hold all your output values till such all inputs are done.

Comment: Okay I accept your answer. But Please answer this question: when I am putting System.out.println() at the end of loop I am getting extra line in my output but when i m skipping it my program is working fine but as there is no linebreak between my output both are sticking together and coming like this: hce akrRn ak. U see this is my main problem. I want to get the output in seperate lines. I have already asked this question above .

Comment: The only linebreak in your code which was unexpected was when you input the final word i.e. "Rank" once done the output should end at Rn ak but your's will end with a extra linebreak, which is unexpected by system. Is this you were asking.

Comment: No I am asking first why in my output I am getting Output "hce akr" after one line even the program is sequential and I am not stating any extra line in output. Second Question is like I have given One "println" at the end of loop so I am skipping it my program is working properly but the spacing and line between output is not coming.

Comment: Firstly run your old code and check how is it displaying the output. There is no way your code could have displayed a line break in start. Just confirm first.

Answer (score 0):

I think the expectation is to take all inputs in one go.
Meaning, once the number of words are given, read all words and then print the output. Since the question is not clear, I am answering based on my assumption.

Comment: Yeah But for that I would need to take String array as input. I want to solve this using only String. My Question is simple: If there is any runtime error in my program what is it. Why it is exiting from loop in first attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not:

> _______________ // first line is getting skipped but if i comment the System
>
> .out.println at the end of loop then both string are coming on same line

, but:

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) { ...
```

...and:

> Error (stderr)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
>       at Solution.main(Solution.java:14)

...with:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { //!!
```

, you'll get:

> Congrats, you solved this challenge!
>   Challenge your friends:
>   Test Case #0
>   Test Case #1
>   Test Case #2
>   Test Case #3
>   Test Case #4
>   Test Case #5
>   Test Case #6
>   Test Case #7
>   Test Case #8
>   Test Case #9

---

... a small style&efficiency improvement would be:

```
...
for(int j = 0; j<str.length() ; j+=2){//!!
    // no if!
    System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
}
System.out.print(" ");
for(int j = 1; j< str.length() ; j+=2){//!!
    //no if!       
    System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
}
...
```

Comment: I already tried to change the loop as per your solution but getting same error.
Here is the output after changing loop:
2
Hacker
Rank
Your Output (stdout)

 
Hce akr
Expected Output

Hce akr
Rn ak
Compiler Message

Wrong Answer

Comment: ...then (the latest issue is) you maybe modified (comparing to original post) ...you talked about "skipping `System.out.print` ...? ..please also copy&paste

Comment: No I just skipped earlier as you can see if we are putting System.out.println() at the end of loop I am getting extra line in my output but when i m skipping it my program is working fine but as there is no linebreak between my output both are sticking together and coming like this: hce akrRn ak. U see this is my main problem. I want to get the output in sperate lines.